# Schooled by a Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

I had a lot of fun writing this riddle, I think it's probably still on the easier side, but hopefully people enjoy it.

> My First is, oh my, a talking horse!
>   My Second is You, but shorter of course.
>   My Third is elemental, good for your bones.
>   My Fourth is a drink which goes well with scones.
>   My Fifth is a moon, of a giant, who knew?
>   My Last is a direction, cardinal, true.
>
> Put me together and what do you find?
>   The path to knowledge, and advancing ones mind.

---

<sub>For those up in the north of the UK - you're going to have to fight your natural pronunciation instincts if you want it to rhyme properly! :)</sub>

Comment: bones and scones, really? It's an affront to my Britishness

Comment: Haha - I did feel a bit guilty about that @Taazar -  but it seems a bit more complex than simply US vs UK English - even in Britain people seem to pronounce it both ways...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is:

> **EDUCATION**

*My First is, oh my, a talking horse!*

> Mister **Ed** was a US TV [sitcom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mister_Ed) about a talking horse.

*My Second is You, but shorter of course.*

> i.e. **U**, text-speak for 'You'.

*My Third is elemental, good for your bones.*

> i.e. **Ca**, the elemental symbol for *calcium*, which is 'good for your bones'.

*My Fourth is a drink which goes well with scones.*

> This is 'tea', or **T** phonetically.

*My Fifth is a moon, of a giant, who knew?*

> **Io** is one of the Galilean [moons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Io_(moon)) of Jupiter.

*My Last is a direction, cardinal, true.*

> This is **N**, short for the cardinal direction, North.

*Put me together and what do you find?*
*The path to knowledge, and advancing ones mind.*

> Altogether we get Ed + U + Ca + T + Io + N, i.e. **Education** - 'the path to knowledge, and advancing one's mind'...

As for the title:

> Education and *school* go hand-in-hand, of course (well, as long as your school is any good!) :)

Comment: Some solid solving skills Stiv, superb!